# Checkbox in Ionic3 in Alert Prompt via AlertController

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, prompt

I am trying to add an Checkbox to my Alert Prompt with the AlertController from Ionic3.

I tried something like this:

```
presentPrompt(name, flaeche) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Parzelle bearbeiten',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'name',
          placeholder: name
        },
        {
          name: 'flaeche',
          placeholder: flaeche
        },
        {
          type: 'checkbox',
        label: 'Bespin',
        value: 'value2',
        checked: true
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Login',
          handler: data => {
            console.log("Login ");
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

But it doesnt work. It would be nice if you could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, according to [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/), this is not possible :(

> Alerts can also include several different inputs whose data can be
>   passed back to the app. Inputs can be used as a simple way to prompt
>   users for information. Radios, checkboxes and text inputs are all
>   accepted, but they cannot be mixed. For example, an alert could have
>   all radio button inputs, or all checkbox inputs, but the same alert
>   cannot mix radio and checkbox inputs. Do note however, different types
>   of "text"" inputs can be mixed, such as url, email, text, etc. If you
>   require a complex form UI which doesn't fit within the guidelines of
>   an alert then we recommend building the form within a modal instead.

Comment: Ah okay... sad story. But Thank you very much